# Understanding Chi Square test on Titanic dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, chi-squared, hypothesis-test

Currently I am working on Hypothesis Testing on datasets.

While reading about chi square tests I found this notebook through Kaggle:

https://github.com/viswanathanc/statistics/blob/master/Titanic%20Chi%20Square%20test%20-%20PClass%20vs%20Survied.ipynb

It is chi square hypothesis testing on titanic dataset.

For calculating relationship between ***class*** and ***survival*** he used this code:

***1) For getting contingency table (observed values)***

`PClass_survd = pd.pivot_table(data,index=['Pclass'],columns=['Survived'],aggfunc='size')`

***2) How class and survival is distributed***

`pct_class = PClass_survd.sum(axis=1)/891`

`pct_survived = PClass_survd.sum(axis=0)/891`

***3) To Calculate Expected Values***

`pct_class.to_frame()@(pct_survived.to_frame().T)`

I don't understand How **expected values** are calculated in step 3. I know `pd.to_frame()` convert series to dataframe.

Can anyone please explain this step 3 in detail or how generally expected values be calculated from dataset without using chi square function from stats (with example if possible) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like you really have a math question, rather than a programming question. Have you tried math.stackexchange.com? Do you understand what the code means, in conventional write-it-out-in-your-math-homework-binder terms? In particular, do you need it explained what the `@` symbol does in this context, or the `.T`? *What exactly is the question*?

Comment: Yes both  `.T` and `@`. Also How it is used for calculating Expected values. Yes It is a maths question linked with hypothesis testing.

Comment: Okay. Are you familiar with pandas and numpy? Did you try reading the documentation?